# File Not Found - Spark standalone cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have two machines named: ubuntu1 and ubuntu2.

In ubuntu1, I started the master node in Spark Standalone Cluster and ubuntu2 I started with a worker (slave).

I am trying to execute the example [workCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java) available on github.

When I submit the application, the worker send an error message

**java.io.FileNotFoundException**: File file:/home/ubuntu1/demo/test.txt does not exist.

My command line is

```
./spark-submit --master spark://ubuntu1-VirtualBox:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --clas br.com.wordCount.App -v --name"Word Count" /home/ubuntu1/demo/wordCount.jar /home/ubuntu1/demo/test.txt
```

The file test.txt has only to stay in one machine ?

**Note:** The master and the worker are in different machine.

Thank you

Comment: Your file should probably be on hdfs.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how are you ? So, Can't I send my text document that way ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem while loading the JSON file. I recognized by default windows storing file format as Textfile regardless of the name. identify the file format then you can load easily.

example: think you saved the file as `test.JSON`. but by default windows adding `.txt` to it.

check that and try to run again.
I hope your problem will get resolved with this idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your file on hdfs by going to the folder and typing :

```
hdfs dfs -put <file>
```

Otherwise each node has to have access to it by having the same path folder existing on each machine.

Don't forget to change file:/ to hdfs:/ after you do that

Comment: When a put this command before file name, throws the error: path does not exist: file:/home/ubunt1/spark2.2/work/driver-201708-0006/hdfs. Thank you for help me.

Comment: yes just replace file:/ at the beginning by hdfs:/ :
hdfs:/home/ubuntu1/demo/test.txt

Comment: sorry, but still the same error :(  :file:/home/ubunt1/spark2.2/work/driver-201708-0006/hdfs

Comment: Did you change the adress in your written program ? Did you first put the file on hdfs ?

Comment: I put your suggestions in my command line before path file, I put: hdfs dfs -put hdfs:/home/ubuntu1/demo/test.txt.

Comment: In the code, I didnt change anything. I am using the spark workCount example. I am trying run this application  in cluster mode and I would like feedback success on worker that the master node selected. Thanks for help me again.

Comment: 1) Make sur that in your program (wordcount.py or wordcount.scala), the file is referenced as hdfs:/test.txt

2) In a terminal, go to the home/ubuntu1/demo folder with cd

3) Enter : hdfs dfs -put test.txt

4) Test again

Comment: When I go the test.txt directory and type the command, it says No command 'hdfs' found. I am using spark2.2, there is something more that I have to install ?